# In what condition Spring call Lifecycle's start/stop hooks?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, lifecycle, applicationcontext

I'm trying to understand the `Lifecycle` interface logic.
The documentation for `Lifecycle` says:

> Containers will propagate start/stop signals to all components that
>   apply within each container, e.g. for a stop/restart scenario at
>   runtime.

But it seems that cantainer doesn't call this methods (start/stop) at all.

For example the result for next code snippet is only single output ">> call: is running: false"

```
@Configuration
public class TestApp implements Lifecycle {

    boolean runStatus = false;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.err.println(">> call: start (Lifecycle)");
        runStatus = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.err.println(">> call: stop (Lifecycle)");
        runStatus = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        System.err.println(">> call: is running: " + runStatus);
        return runStatus;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestApp.class);
        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```

P.S. I heard about `SmartLifecycle` and it works fine. But I'm interesting in how can we correctly use the start/stop methods from `Lifecycle`.

Comment: The spring documentation also says: "Note that the Lifecycle interface is only supported on top-level singleton beans. On any other component, the Lifecycle interface will remain undetected and hence ignored. Also, note that the extended SmartLifecycle interface provides integration with the application context's startup and shutdown phases."
Maybe it doesn't work because you use it on a configuration class? I would suggest you try it on a Bean class

Comment: This article may help https://jstobigdata.com/spring/spring-bean-lifecycle-callbacks/#4_spring_lifecycle_interface_startup_and_shutdown_callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should manually `start()` and `stop()` the context.

```
@Configuration
 public class TestApp implements Lifecycle {

  boolean runStatus = false;

  public TestApp (){}


  @Bean
  public TestApp testApp(){
    return new TestApp();
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {
    System.err.println(">> call: start (Lifecycle)");
    runStatus = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    System.err.println(">> call: stop (Lifecycle)");
    runStatus = false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isRunning() {
    System.err.println(">> call: is running: " + runStatus);
    return runStatus;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestApp.class);
    ctx.start();
    TestApp ta = ctx.getBean(TestApp.class);
    ctx.stop();
  }
}
```